# RSpec testing an error is thrown, ActiveRecord connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, rspec

I'm doing a funny thing in a Rails app, connecting to a different DB to read information, but not write it. For ease of making these connections, I wrote models to handle the tables. I have two similar classes, so here's one to get the point across:

```
# call.rb
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  # We don't want to change these values in the table, only read them
  attr_reader :uniqueid, :queue, :agent_id, :codes, :code_count

  def self.connect
    establish_connection "ihs"
    self.table_name = 'calls'
  end

  def self.disconnect
    self.connection.close
  end
end
```

I don't want this connection to override the main connection to the Rails app's DB, it's just a temporary thing. So now, I want to test that these connections are actually established and closed whenever I call these methods. At the moment, this is what I've thought of:

```
# call_spec.rb
describe Call do

  [code omitted]

  describe "#connect" do
    # before { Call.disconnect }

    it "establishes a connection to IHS DB" do
      puts Call.count
      lambda { Call.count }.should raise_error(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
      Call.connect
      lambda { Call.count }.should_not raise_error
    end
  end
end
```

I've tested this code using a `begin ... rescue Exception => e; puts e.class; end` to verify the type of exception thrown, and it is indeed an ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid exception, but this test is not passing. The error I'm being thrown reads as follows:

```
Failure/Error: puts Call.count
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
    PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "calls" does not exist
      [rest omitted]
```

This is the error I'm expecting to get, I just don't know how to tweak the test in order to pass. Any tips?

Comment: 2 things I noticed, first, the call to `Call.count` just before the real exception is here only for the purpose of debugging ? cause if t's not, it might the one throwing the exception, and why aren't you using the traditional `expect{}.to raise_error` see https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-6/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher ?

Comment: haha wow. Can't believe it was right in front of me the whole time. Thanks so much! Leave an answer and I'll accept that right up for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to

```
puts Call.count
```

right before the actual exception, is raising the error before rspec 'catches' it.

Comment: To answer your second question in the comment, I found the lambda syntax to mirror more closely the format of my other tests (using `should` and `should_not` rather than `to` and `not_to`). Just seemed to read a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why it's important to explicitly connect and disconnect? In one app where I want to connect to a secondary database to read, I have all the activerecord classes inherit from a base class that takes care of the connection, something like this:

```
class IhsActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_ihs"
end
```

This way you're not constantly reconnecting and disconnecting, and you can keep the connection logic in one place. The actual connection information can still go in your database.yml file. Above, I have a separate one per environment, you can adjust as long as it matches your database.yml.

I also recommend using expect {} in your spec instead of lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I believe I've tried making connection in this way before, and it seemed to mess up my base connections (to the DB the Rails app was using), so I was trying a different approach. Additionally, this DB is only one that I need to pull info from, not update in any way, so I wanted to make sure it was only accessible when it was absolutely necessary. Does that make sense, or am I missing the mark a bit still?

Comment: At least some databases have a big performance hit when connecting, so for that reason I would try to avoid doing that. You might look at the comments here  about making a model reaonly: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/readonly%3F and maybe also define your own empty 'delete' and 'destroy' methods, or versions that raise exceptions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the pointer! I just finished implementing those methods, and feel much more secure about the model as a whole now.